# Get lost commits on GIT

Tags: github, git-commit

Me and my partners are working on the git remote and both have write access to the remote.

He did some changes, commited them and pushed them to remote,

I did few changes in my machine and without fetching/pulling just force pushed my commits.
Which in turn resulted in lost of the commits of my partner.

So I have 2 questions:

**1. Is there any way to get those commits back?**

**2. After my push, will my partners fetch, pull remove the changes he did, from his machine as well?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you push commits that overwrite someone else's code, and didn't pull; git will throw an error something like this:

```
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:foo'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes before pushing again.  See the 'non-fast forward'
section of 'git push --help' for details.
```

On the off chance that you actually did overwrite something, you can revert your entire git repo. See this stack overflow question for an example:
[How do I restore files to previous states in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35284/how-do-i-restore-files-to-previous-states-in-git)

Comment: It was my **BAD** that I actually did Force push